# Como editar/escribir en una plantilla en excel con PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, php7, phpspreadsheet

tengo un documento en excel .xlsx y algunas celdas contienen información predeterminada y quiero escribir sobre ese documento sin que se borre la información que ya contiene, pero en lugar de eso se sobre escribe quedado solo el valor que le asigne a la celda y se borra todo lo demás, y no sé como hacer para mantener esos datos pre-cargados y agregar mas valores a otras celdas
ejemplo de mi documento de excel:

[image: Quiero escribir en la celda B4]

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("prueba.xlsx");
try {

$spread = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spread->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle("Plantilla");
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, 3, "Valor");
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spread, 'Xlsx');
$sheet->setCellValue("B4", "Valor B4");
$writer->save("prueba.xlsx");

} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo 'Ocurrió un error al intentar abrir el archivo ' . $e;
}
```

Comment: ¿Queres agregar información pero en las celdas donde previamente no habia? Es decir, necesitas escribir en celdas vacias, correcto?

Comment: Así es, necesito poder agregar información manteniendo la que ya estaba

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por que estas generando una nueva instancia de Spreadsheet `$spread = new Spreadsheet();` al hacer eso creas y editas un documento diferente al que acabas de cargar puede probar lo siguiente:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("prueba.xlsx");
try {

//$spread = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle("Plantilla");
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, 3, "Valor");
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spread, 'Xlsx');
$sheet->setCellValue("B4", "Valor B4");
$writer->save("prueba.xlsx");

} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo 'Ocurrió un error al intentar abrir el archivo ' . $e;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Se que esto fue hace mucho tiempo, pero estoy trabajando en Laravel con este tema y lo que me sucede es que cuando guardo la instancia del archivo con otro nombre me elimina una imagen y el formato de algunos títulos que ya existían en el XLS. Los nuevos datos se guardan bien, pero desaparecen los formatos de los títulos y elimina una imagen que tenia en ese xls. Alguién sabe porque ?